# finding the text before the keyword using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

My String

```
$string = "Name : Test 123 \n req string : abc xyz 123 bla bla \n tel:234545";
```

my keyword is

```
$keyword = 'tel';
```

Now, I need to find the text before my keyword. I can able to find the words after the keyword using

```
$pattern  = '/\btel\W*(.*)$/mi';
```

But, I need a pattern from which I can find the text before the keyword. Means, I need to get `abc xyz 123 bla bla` if my keyword is `tel`.
I think you got what I said.

```
Note : I need only the required string. But not Name. Thats the reason, I am not using explode.
```

plz help me in solving this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not split on `tel` and take the first element of the resulting array?

Comment: Plz check the note in my question

Comment: **Why don't you take time to write the whole question and then post it ? You have totally changed the question and answers below are deemed invalid.**

Comment: The question is not changed completely. I edited it for better understanding

Comment: This was your first string `$string = "abc xyz 123 bla bla \n tel:234545";` now you changed the whole string itself.

Comment: don't get angry yaar, I just appended `"Name : Test 123 \n req string : ` to the string. This is some other case. I added this for the better understanding of the people. I dont know why you are getting angry about this.

Comment: Even then you can use explode, just now in this case you need to use explode twice, still i find it the easiest option!

Comment: @Gireesh Edited my answer, perhps this can help!

Comment: @Gireesh: commenting on your own post to ask for help has no effect, noone new will be notified. Instead, you could try the answers people have already offered (and comment on them if they don't do the job)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex then:

```
([^:\r\n]+)[\r\n]+tel
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bP7zO7)

`[^:\r\n]+` matches non colon/newlines/carriage returns.

`[\r\n]+` matches newlines/carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex by looking ahead:

```
/(.*)(?=(tel))/
```

I don't know about the php specific rules of regex but I hope you get the idea. Also, you should use the DOTALL parameter to include matching newlines

Demo:

http://regex101.com/r/mZ0wT5

Comment: This doesn't really allow multiline support, and you might want to put `tel` inside word boundaries (to see with OP I guess). Also the `?` is pointless, `.*` will always match something (even if this match is an empty string)